# I want to fetch columns using models in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Hello I want to display the `first_name, last_name, subject` from the tables using models in laravel after the search but whenever I try to find `subject_name` using the models I get error below

`Exception
Property [subjects] does not exist on this collection instance.`

My search functionality is working fine I am just having a problem with displaying the results i.e. `first_name, last_name, subject`.

I tried to fetch the results from the search keywords and it returned the array of the search matched now I want to display its specific columns that I mentioned above.

**User Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use App\UserType;
use App\Subject;
use App\SubjectKeyword;
use App\Review;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'type', 'username', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getAllUsers() {
        return User::all();
     }

    public function userTypes()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Users');
    }

    // public function subjects()
    // {
    //     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject');
    // }

    public function subjects(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Subject','subject_id','id');
    }

    public function reviews(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
    }

    public function subjectKeywords(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\SubjectKeyword');
    }
}
```

**Subject Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;
use App\SubjectKeyword;

class Subject extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'subject_name', 
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }

    public function subjectKeywords()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SUbjectKeyword');
    }
}
```

**SubjectKeyword Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Subject;

class SubjectKeyword extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'keyword_title1', 'keyword_title2', 'keyword_title3', 'keyword_title4', 'keyword_title5', 
    ];

    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Subject','subject_id','id');
    }

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
    }
}
```

**subjectkeywords table**

```
Schema::create('subject_keywords', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('subject_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('keyword_title1')->nullable();
            $table->string('keyword_title2')->nullable();
            $table->string('keyword_title3')->nullable();
            $table->string('keyword_title4')->nullable();
            $table->string('keyword_title5')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**subjects table**

```
 Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('subject_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**users table**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_type_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('university_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
            $table->integer('subject_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('country')->nullable();
            $table->string('year_of_study')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This is my **Controller** where I am performing the search

```
public function searchMentor(Request $request) {

        $search = Input::get('search');

        if($search != "") {

            $find = SubjectKeyword::where("keyword_title1",'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                                    ->orWhere("keyword_title2",'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                                    ->orWhere("keyword_title3",'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                                    ->orWhere("keyword_title4",'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                                    ->orWhere("keyword_title5",'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->get();

            if(count($find)>0) {

                echo $find;
                dd($find->subjects->subject_name);
                // echo $find->user->first_name;
                die();
                return view('review.showReviewPage', compact('find', 'search'));
            } else {
                Session::flash('message', 'No keyword matched');
                return redirect('/home');
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
```

**View**

```
@extends('layout.genericLayout')
@section('title', 'List of Mentors')

@section('content')

<p>if have any content that will go here<p>

@endsection

@section('details')

list of mentors <br/>

@section('content2')

<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

@if(isset($find))
<p>The search result for your query {{ $search }} are: </p>

  <h1> Sample User Details </h1>

  <table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Expert Subject</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Overall Ratings</th>
<tr>

  @foreach($find as $find)
<tr>
    <td> {{ $find->subject->first_name }} </td>
    <td> {{ $find['keyword_title2'] }}</td>
    <td> {{ $find['city'] }} </td>
    <td> {{ $find['country'] }} </td>
    <td> </td>

</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
@endif

@endsection
@endsection
```

Error when I try to iterate in view

`ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property 'first_name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myUniMentor\resources\views\review\showReviewPage.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Trying to get property 'first_name' of non-object (0)`

Comment: `$find` is a collection of multiple `SubjectKeyword`s. If you want the subject_name, you have to iterate over the collection and query each individual keyword.

Comment: thank you for your response aynber. I have updated my view too so that you have a look on it too and guide me in a proper way. I did try to iterate in my view but that was the error I was getting.

Comment: `@foreach($find as $find)` is going to cause you problems. You're overwriting the collection with the individual model the first loop. On the second, you're going to iterate through the object properties. Change the variable on the right to something else, such as `@foreach($find as $f)`, then use that to get the properties `$f->subject->first_name`

Comment: yes this worked. I didnt have idea about this. I thought of doing this but then I thought that there shouldnt be any difference on this. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: when I search this, it shows the result which is perfect but when I refresh the page it shows the blank page where it should show the result which is already searched. is it like for session or something ?

Comment: Make sure the variable stays when you refresh the page. If the search is via GET, then it should still be in the URL. If it's via POST, then the variable will disappear.

Comment: I also have get method so if I refresh it. it should run that. no ? `Route::get('/search-mentor', 'MentorController@searchMentor'); Route::post('/search-mentor', 'MentorController@searchMentor');`

Answer (score 0):

Your $find is a collection which has more than just one instance.
You need to iterate through it and get all of the subjects

Comment: thank you for your response edward. I have updated my view too so that you have a look on it too and guide me in a proper way. I did try to iterate in my view but that was the error I was getting.

Comment: I think the issue is with line *"dd($find->subjects->subject_name)"*, here it is not iterated but being used as a collection. That is in your searchMentor function

Comment: which line are you talking about here ?

Comment: Asad, please check if the comment above helps ;)

Comment: Aynber's comment on the post helped me. I was overwriting the collection with the individual model the first loop in my view so I changed it as per Aynbers suggestion and it worked

Comment: Cool, all the best pal!

Comment: when I search this, it shows the result which is perfect but when I refresh the page it shows the blank page where it should show the result which is already searched. is it like for session or something ?

Comment: If you refresh the page, it will only go through your defined route **without resubmitting the POST request.** Hence your searchMentor function will not be run again and the result won't persist

Comment: I also have get method so if I refresh it. it should run that. no ? `Route::get('/search-mentor', 'MentorController@searchMentor');
Route::post('/search-mentor', 'MentorController@searchMentor');`